# I upload a package to packagist.org and why i can't require it?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, package

[packagist link](https://packagist.org/packages/rrylee/presenter)

[github link](https://github.com/RryLee/Presenter/)

This is my composer.json:

```
json
{
    "name": "rrylee/presenter",
    "type": "library",
    "description": "Simple view presenters",
    "keywords": [
        "presenter",
        "laravel5",
        "view"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "RryLee",
            "email": "qq215672398@126.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "illuminate/support": "5.0.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpspec/phpspec": "^2.2",
        "mockery/mockery": "^0.9.4"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "Rrylee\\Presenter": "src/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

When my composer require rrylee/presenter or composer install:

```
{
    "require": {
        "rrylee/presenter": "0.1.*"
    },
}
```

I always get errors

> Could not find package rrylee/presenter at any version for your minimum-stability
>      (stable). Check the package spelling or your minimum-stability

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Now that you've updated the package name, I'm able to pull it into a project:

`composer require rrylee/presenter`

My composer.json looks like:

```
{
    "require": {
        "rrylee/presenter": "^0.1.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please help me by pulling a request fix it or others

Comment: amazing! Thank you vert muck